# Can Iranian/German dual citizen transit in Iran on the German passport?

Tags: transit-visas, dual-nationality, iran, german-citizens, iranian-citizens

I'm in the airport and met an Iranian/German dual citizen.

He is not carrying his Iranian passport. 
He is 18 years old and if found out, he should do military service in Iran.

Is it possible for him to transit in Iran? Or can he get in trouble?

Sorry for the quick question, flight is departing in one hour and a half.

Answer (score 3):

In general no.  A Iranian is Iranian on own country, so he must use Iranian passport and use rules that applies on Iranian people.

The same in Germany (with German passport).

Just abroad of the two countries, you have the choice, also because both countries have no legal authority.

Comment: In Germany, there is no requirement that German citizens with additional citizenships must use their German documents to identify themselfes. If they want, they can use their foreign citizenship both for immigration and for internal purposes.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Are you sure? Note: for simple identification, every official identification cards with photo are valid, but this is just identification. But to pass boundaries and for official/legal acts, as far I know, a German should provide a German identifications.  A short google gave me: http://www.stern.de/tv/deutscher-und-tuerkischer-pass--das-sollten-sie-ueber-die-doppelte-staatsbuergerschaft-wissen-7378140.html : " Reist ein Deutschtürke nach Deutschland ein, muss er den Behörden den deutschen Pass vorlegen – reist er in die Türkei, ist es umgekehrt.".

Comment: Yes, I am sure. A dual German/Turkish citizen must use the German passport to enter Germany, but not because dual citizens are required to use the German passport. The reason is that Turkish citizens need a visa to enter Germany, which he will not get, because of the German citizenship. The option to use a foreign citizenship for immigration purposes is therefore in practice limited to EEA or visa-free countries.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi note that Stern is not an official source.  Journalists often post incorrect information about immigration law.